# Package nomencl not generating .nlo file

Tags: nomenclature

For some reason when I process with pdflatex and work with `makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o EncFor.nls EncFor.nlo` 
The nomenclature is just not showing up. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx, imakeidx, afterpage}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, epigraph, etoolbox, amssymb}
%\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}

%----------------WATER MARK AND TITLE--------------
\newcommand*{\titleUL}{\begingroup
\drop=0.1\textheight
\vspace*{\drop}
\begin{center}
{\LARGE\textsc{UNIVERSIDAD NACIONAL AUT\'ONOMA DE M\'EXICO}\\[\drop]
% University logo
{\LARGE \plogo}\\[\drop]
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\par
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
{\huge\bfseries Encyclop\ae dia Formul\ae\\
\large --- in N pages, with T tables ---}\\
[0.5\baselineskip]
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\par
\vfill
{\Large\textsc{The\EncFortnote{\texttt{email address}} Candidate}}
\vfill
City, Country
\vfill
{\large The Date}
\end{center}%
\endgroup}
}
\setcounter{page}{0}
%-------------------------------------------------
\SetWatermarkText{DRAFT}
\SetWatermarkScale{5}
\makeindex[columns=2, intoc]
\makeglossaries

%------------ glossary entries
\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
  name=latex,
  description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
    for scientific documents}
}

%-----------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\titleUL
%-------------------COVER PAGE page 0-------------------%

%------------------------------------------------------
\frontmatter
\newpage            % false page i.
\newpage            % false page ii.
%--------------------TITLE PAGE iii------------------------%
\author{Karl Ruprecht Kr\"{o}nen}   % agregar adscripcion e.g. Ph.D. FRS.
\title{Encyclop\ae dia Formul\ae}
% nombre de la casa editora
% nombre del resivor tecnico con sus adscripciones
\date{}
\maketitle
%------------------LEGAL PAGE iv-----------------------%
LEGAL PAGE
%----------------- first half--------------------------%
%Creditos para el editor, supervisor y tipografo        % numero de edicion
% leyenda explicativa del motivo de la portada o creditos
%-------------------second half-------------------------%
% letras mayusculas: titulo y numbero de edicion, tomo o volumen, ultima linea sea anota la ciudad y el pais donde se imprimio.
% enseguida se inscribe la leyenda de copyright y el anio de publicacion y el nombre de la persona fisica o moral que reserva los derechos asi como su direccion
% LETRAS NEGRITAS NUMBERO ISBN
% finalmente se escribe en la parte infrerior el pais de publicacion.
\newpage
%--------------- DEDICATIONS v------------------------%
DEDICATIONS PAGE
\newpage
%--------------- ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS vi------------------%
ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS PAGE
\newpage
%-----------------CONTENTS vii till ?? ----------------------%
\tableofcontents % starts visible roman numbering
%-------------------PREFACE--keeps roman numerals starting from ??----------%
% starts presenting the work and expresses the reason for its writing & identifies the audience
% explains briefly the contents of the work & or chapters and gives an indication for the methodology of the reading. 
% more acknowledgements and thanks to everyone who supported the manuscript &/or the writing itself.
%-----------------STARTS TEXT & arabic numerals------------------------
\listoffigures

\listoftables
\mainmatter
\part{First Part of this document}

\epigraph{\textit{Indeed, the purpose of an encyclopedia is to collect knowledge\index{knowledge} \gls{latex} disseminated around the globe; to set forth its general system to the men with whom we live, and transmit it to those who will come after us, so that the work of preceding centuries\index{knowledge!centuries} will not become useless to the centuries to come; and so that our offspring, becoming better instructed\index{centuries!instructed}, will at the same time become more virtuous and happy, and that we should not die without having rendered a service to the human race in the future years to come.}}{\textsc{Diderot}}

\chapter{Mathematics}
    \section{Probability}
    \label{sec:probability}
    First section, \gls{latex} is pretty good.
    \section{Statistics}
    \label{sec:statistics}
    Probability's\index{Probability} section number is ~\ref{sec:probability}, while this section's number is ~\ref{sec:statistics}.
    \newtheorem{AMean}{Arithmetic Mean}[section]
    \newtheorem{WAMean}{Weighted Arithmetic Mean}
    For a set of data
    $$ \{ x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n \} $$
    \begin{AMean}
    The arithmetic mean is defined\footnote{or can be deduced logically} as follows :
    \label{eq:Mean}
    \begin{equation}
        \label{eq:Arithmetic Mean}
        \bar{x}:=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}{n}
        \end{equation}
    \end{AMean}
    \begin{WAMean}
        \begin{equation}
        \label{eq:Weighted Arithmetic Mean}
        \bar{x}_w:=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_iw_i}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i}
        \end{equation}
    \end{WAMean}
    \begin{proof}
    This is not provable because it is a definition.
    \end{proof}
    Luego decimos que la \ref{eq:Arithmetic Mean} es mayor que la secci\'on \ref{sec:probability}.\\
    Luego \gls{latex} es chingon.
%------------------------------------------------------------
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{thebibliography}{}

    \bibitem{Zeevaert} 
        Zeevaert, L.,
      \emph{Foundation engineering for difficult subsoil conditions},
      Van Nonstrand Reinhold, 
      New York, 
      2nd edition, 
      \textbf{1983}.

\end{thebibliography}
%-------------NOMENCLATURE-------------%
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
 \item[\bfseries
 \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Physics Constants}{%
\ifstrequal{#1}{B}{Number Sets}{%
\ifstrequal{#1}{C}{Other Symbols}{}}}%
]}
%This will add the units
%----------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}}
%----------------------------------------------
\nomenclature[A, 02]{$c$}{Speed of light in a vacuum
inertial system 
    \nomunit{$299,792,458\, m/s$}}
\nomenclature[A, 03]{$h$}{Plank Constant
    \nomunit{$6.62607 \times 10^{-34}\, Js$}}
\nomenclature[A, 01]{$g$}{Gravitational Constant 
    \nomunit{$6.67384 \times 10^{-11}\, N \cdot m^2/kg^2$}}
\nomenclature[B, 03]{$\mathbb{R}$}{Real Numbers}
\nomenclature[B, 02]{$\mathbb{C}$}{Complex Numbers}
\nomenclature[B, 01]{$\mathbb{H}$}{Quaternions}
\nomenclature[C]{$V$}{Constant Volume}
\nomenclature[C]{$\rho$}{Friction Index}
%APPENDIXES
%------------------------------------------------------------
\printnomenclature
\glsaddall
\printglossaries
%------------------------------------------------------------
\printindex
\end{document}


pdfLaTeX EncFor.tex
makeindex EncFor.glo -s nomencl.ist -o EncFor.nls
pdfLaTeX EncFor.tex
```

Comment: This is somehow the same question as the other one (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273618/how-to-make-glossary-and-nomenclature-show-up-in-contents-how-to-make-the-cover) , where I answered already and the `\makenomenclature` command was in in my answer ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot `\makenomenclature` in the preamble! If this command is missing, no `.nlo` file is generated and as a consequence, the `makeindex -s nomencl.ist....` sequence fails, not producing the final `.nls` file.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx, imakeidx, afterpage}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, epigraph, etoolbox, amssymb}
%\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}

%----------------WATER MARK AND TITLE--------------
\newcommand*{\titleUL}{\begingroup
\drop=0.1\textheight
\vspace*{\drop}
\begin{center}
{\LARGE\textsc{UNIVERSIDAD NACIONAL AUT\'ONOMA DE M\'EXICO}\\[\drop]
% University logo
{\LARGE \plogo}\\[\drop]
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\par
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
{\huge\bfseries Encyclop\ae dia Formul\ae\\
\large --- in N pages, with T tables ---}\\
[0.5\baselineskip]
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\par
\vfill
{\Large\textsc{The\EncFortnote{\texttt{email address}} Candidate}}
\vfill
City, Country
\vfill
{\large The Date}
\end{center}%
\endgroup}
}
\setcounter{page}{0}
%-------------------------------------------------
\SetWatermarkText{DRAFT}
\SetWatermarkScale{5}

%%%%% Inserted \makenomenclature

\makenomenclature

%%%%%%%% 
\makeindex[columns=2, intoc]
\makeglossaries

%------------ glossary entries
\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
  name=latex,
  description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
    for scientific documents}
}

%-----------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\titleUL
%-------------------COVER PAGE page 0-------------------%

%------------------------------------------------------
\frontmatter
\newpage            % false page i.
\newpage            % false page ii.
%--------------------TITLE PAGE iii------------------------%
\author{Karl Ruprecht Kr\"{o}nen}   % agregar adscripcion e.g. Ph.D. FRS.
\title{Encyclop\ae dia Formul\ae}
% nombre de la casa editora
% nombre del resivor tecnico con sus adscripciones
\date{}
\maketitle
%------------------LEGAL PAGE iv-----------------------%
LEGAL PAGE
%----------------- first half--------------------------%
%Creditos para el editor, supervisor y tipografo        % numero de edicion
% leyenda explicativa del motivo de la portada o creditos
%-------------------second half-------------------------%
% letras mayusculas: titulo y numbero de edicion, tomo o volumen, ultima linea sea anota la ciudad y el pais donde se imprimio.
% enseguida se inscribe la leyenda de copyright y el anio de publicacion y el nombre de la persona fisica o moral que reserva los derechos asi como su direccion
% LETRAS NEGRITAS NUMBERO ISBN
% finalmente se escribe en la parte infrerior el pais de publicacion.
\newpage
%--------------- DEDICATIONS v------------------------%
DEDICATIONS PAGE
\newpage
%--------------- ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS vi------------------%
ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS PAGE
\newpage
%-----------------CONTENTS vii till ?? ----------------------%
\tableofcontents % starts visible roman numbering
%-------------------PREFACE--keeps roman numerals starting from ??----------%
% starts presenting the work and expresses the reason for its writing & identifies the audience
% explains briefly the contents of the work & or chapters and gives an indication for the methodology of the reading. 
% more acknowledgements and thanks to everyone who supported the manuscript &/or the writing itself.
%-----------------STARTS TEXT & arabic numerals------------------------
\listoffigures

\listoftables
\mainmatter
\part{First Part of this document}

\epigraph{\textit{Indeed, the purpose of an encyclopedia is to collect knowledge\index{knowledge} \gls{latex} disseminated around the globe; to set forth its general system to the men with whom we live, and transmit it to those who will come after us, so that the work of preceding centuries\index{knowledge!centuries} will not become useless to the centuries to come; and so that our offspring, becoming better instructed\index{centuries!instructed}, will at the same time become more virtuous and happy, and that we should not die without having rendered a service to the human race in the future years to come.}}{\textsc{Diderot}}

\chapter{Mathematics}
    \section{Probability}
    \label{sec:probability}
    First section, \gls{latex} is pretty good.
    \section{Statistics}
    \label{sec:statistics}
    Probability's\index{Probability} section number is ~\ref{sec:probability}, while this section's number is ~\ref{sec:statistics}.
    \newtheorem{AMean}{Arithmetic Mean}[section]
    \newtheorem{WAMean}{Weighted Arithmetic Mean}
    For a set of data
    $$ \{ x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n \} $$
    \begin{AMean}
    The arithmetic mean is defined\footnote{or can be deduced logically} as follows :
    \label{eq:Mean}
    \begin{equation}
        \label{eq:Arithmetic Mean}
        \bar{x}:=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}{n}
        \end{equation}
    \end{AMean}
    \begin{WAMean}
        \begin{equation}
        \label{eq:Weighted Arithmetic Mean}
        \bar{x}_w:=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_iw_i}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i}
        \end{equation}
    \end{WAMean}
    \begin{proof}
    This is not provable because it is a definition.
    \end{proof}
    Luego decimos que la \ref{eq:Arithmetic Mean} es mayor que la secci\'on \ref{sec:probability}.\\
    Luego \gls{latex} es chingon.
%------------------------------------------------------------
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{thebibliography}{}

    \bibitem{Zeevaert} 
        Zeevaert, L.,
      \emph{Foundation engineering for difficult subsoil conditions},
      Van Nonstrand Reinhold, 
      New York, 
      2nd edition, 
      \textbf{1983}.

\end{thebibliography}
%-------------NOMENCLATURE-------------%
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
 \item[\bfseries
 \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Physics Constants}{%
\ifstrequal{#1}{B}{Number Sets}{%
\ifstrequal{#1}{C}{Other Symbols}{}}}%
]}
%This will add the units
%----------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}}
%----------------------------------------------
\nomenclature[A, 02]{$c$}{Speed of light in a vacuum
inertial system 
    \nomunit{$299,792,458\, m/s$}}
\nomenclature[A, 03]{$h$}{Plank Constant
    \nomunit{$6.62607 \times 10^{-34}\, Js$}}
\nomenclature[A, 01]{$g$}{Gravitational Constant 
    \nomunit{$6.67384 \times 10^{-11}\, N \cdot m^2/kg^2$}}
\nomenclature[B, 03]{$\mathbb{R}$}{Real Numbers}
\nomenclature[B, 02]{$\mathbb{C}$}{Complex Numbers}
\nomenclature[B, 01]{$\mathbb{H}$}{Quaternions}
\nomenclature[C]{$V$}{Constant Volume}
\nomenclature[C]{$\rho$}{Friction Index}
%APPENDIXES
%------------------------------------------------------------
\printnomenclature
\glsaddall
\printglossaries
%------------------------------------------------------------
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]